# Windows 8.1: 100% Disk usages at Startup. How to overcome?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, windows-8.1

First of all here is the screenshot of the program that causes trouble when I boot my laptop.

Service host taking 100% disk:

[image: service host taking 100% disk]

When I boot my Laptop up disk usages remains 100% for almost 5 minutes and if I have an internet connection and if I open chrome, the download speed goes up to 5 Mbps. Then I  have use resource monitor to end that processes. I have disabled all the startup programs and also disabled prefetch and other services. But this problem persists. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Edit your reply and add your HW configuration. (With information you have provided, the most straightforward solution is to get SSD instead your current disk.)

Comment: It's hard to tell from that screenshot alone what's actually causing the high disk usage. You'll have to look further to see which service is actually causing it. Couple that disk access to what seems like low memory and things will only get worse (swapping).  You might want to use a tool like Process Explorer to or at least check disk access in the resource monitor to see where so much disk access is coming from.

Comment: You probably also need to re-enable prefetch & whatever else you thought was the cause. No machine will be faster with prefetch off. If you're running from an HD that is not going to help at all. Modern operating systems [even 8.1] expect to be running from SSD. Windows has traditionally *always* pretended it's ready to go long before it actually is. When you get to the desktop it's really only half way there. On older OSes & with HDD this is much more noticeable. On a modern machine with SSD/NVME etc, you hardly notice.